# bootstrap 4 can not get offset col to work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap and I'm trying to make offset with Boostrap 4 but after trying a hour and nothing work, here is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
        <title>Hellow World!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
    <header class="col-md-12">HEADER</header>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">1/3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">1/3</div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to replace **offset-md-4** with **col-md-offset-4** but still not work. Can someone figure this out?

Comment: are you sure you included valid bootstrap version?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which Bootstrap version are you using, but from that Popper JS include, I'm guessing Bootstrap 4 (beta).

Bootstrap 4 (beta) [does not have offset classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) for columns:

> With the move to flexbox in v4, we no longer have v3’s style of offset classes. Instead, use margin utilities like `.mr-auto` to force sibling columns away from one another.

[Alpha version had offset classes though](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns), but I encourage you to switch to beta, as every further version will build upon this.

In Bootstrap 4, you can achive column offsetting by adding [margin utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) to columns. For example:

```css
.row {
    background: red;
}

.row > div {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 ml-auto">1/3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">1/3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to stick with the alpha version, your above code should work if you include Bootstrap 4 alpha CSS:

```css
.row {
    background: red;
}

.row > div {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">1/3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">1/3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** [Bootstrap 4 beta 2](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/10/19/bootstrap-4-beta-2/) brings back these [offset classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)! So if you include the new CSS, you can use your original code.

Comment: I updated my post because Bootstrap 4 beta 2 has just been released and it brings back the offset classes.

Answer (score 0):

First you check bootstrap version.this might help you. 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19966